# Error while trying to load dictionary data into a Data Frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd 
data={'Company':['GOOG','GOOG','MSFT','MSFT','FB','FB'],'Person':['Sam','charlie','Amy','vanessa','Sarah'],'Sales':[200,120,340,124,243,350]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

And here is the error:

---

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-039b238b38ef> in <module>
----> 1 df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: Sales has one more item that the rest of the lists

Comment: Sales and Company have 6 values whereas Person has 5 values.

Comment: Here is the next part of the error:c:\users\ahmed\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __init__(self, data, index, columns, dtype, copy)
    466 
    467         elif isinstance(data, dict):
--> 468             mgr = init_dict(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype)
    469         elif isinstance(data, ma.MaskedArray):
    470             import numpy.ma.mrecords as mrecords

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you this code:

```
import pandas as pd 
data={'Company':['GOOG','GOOG','MSFT','MSFT','FB','FB'],'Person': 
['Sam','charlie','Amy','vanessa','Sarah'],'Sales':[200,120,340,124,243,350]}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='index')
df = df.transpose()
print(df)
```

output is:

```
  Company   Person Sales
  0    GOOG      Sam   200
  1    GOOG  charlie   120
  2    MSFT      Amy   340
  3    MSFT  vanessa   124
  4      FB    Sarah   243
  5      FB     None   350
```